# Using query string in asp slideshow for an attribute href

Tags: asp.net, variables, query-string, slideshow

I use to get a query string from a page :

```
   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkAlbum1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="Photos.aspx?Album=1"><img src="images/CircleMenu/thumbs/1.jpg" alt=""/></asp:HyperLink>
```

Also I have this asp code in Photos.aspx page:

```
   <a href="images/prettyPhoto/<%=Album%>/fullscreen/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery2]" title="">
    <img src="images/prettyPhoto/<%=Album%>/fullscreen/1.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="" />
```

I want to get dynamic the <%=Album%> value and use it to assign the right path on the slide show.How can I assign in the <%=Album%> value the query string Album?

I add this to c#

```
protected string Album ;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     var Album = Request.QueryString.ToString();

}
```

behind but it doesn't give the value on html that I want. I also use <%# Album%> but nothing...

Comment: <%= will work in asp.net page while if you are using databound controls use <%#

Answer (score 0):

Use Session
For more info..check out this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx